# Heroku status 500 error after deploying Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, http-status-code-500

```
$heroku logs --tail 
Started GET "/" for 46.188.182.234 at 2016-11-14 20:51:53 +0000
2016-11-14T20:51:53.840163+00:00 app[web.1]: [21c27115-512c-4e9e-bb24-8e1d8b0a46ca] Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2016-11-14T20:51:53.850654+00:00 app[web.1]: [21c27115-512c-4e9e-bb24-8e1d8b0a46ca]   Rendering static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
2016-11-14T20:51:53.856619+00:00 app[web.1]: [21c27115-512c-4e9e-bb24-8e1d8b0a46ca]   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (5.7ms)
2016-11-14T20:51:53.859704+00:00 app[web.1]: [21c27115-512c-4e9e-bb24-8e1d8b0a46ca] Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 11.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-11-14T20:51:59.479887+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/signup" host=damp-reef-30485.herokuapp.com request_id=79382bce-34fd-4faa-958c-15b6ce8adf1f fwd="46.188.182.234" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=64ms status=500 bytes=1733
2016-11-14T20:51:59.487241+00:00 app[web.1]: [79382bce-34fd-4faa-958c-15b6ce8adf1f] Started GET "/signup" for 46.188.182.234 at 2016-11-14 20:51:59 +0000
2016-11-14T20:51:59.495254+00:00 app[web.1]: [79382bce-34fd-4faa-958c-15b6ce8adf1f] Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
2016-11-14T20:51:59.509968+00:00 app[web.1]: [79382bce-34fd-4faa-958c-15b6ce8adf1f] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511411+00:00 app[web.1]: [79382bce-34fd-4faa-958c-15b6ce8adf1f]   
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511456+00:00 app[web.1]: [79382bce-34fd-4faa-958c-15b6ce8adf1f] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511457+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511457+00:00 app[web.1]:                                           ^
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511458+00:00 app[web.1]: :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511458+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511459+00:00 app[web.1]:              (SELECT c.collname FROM pg_collation c, pg_type t
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511459+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE c.oid = a.attcollation AND t.oid = a.atttypid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation),
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511460+00:00 app[web.1]:                      col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511460+00:00 app[web.1]:                 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511461+00:00 app[web.1]:                   ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511461+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511462+00:00 app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511462+00:00 app[web.1]:                ORDER BY a.attnum
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511463+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511491+00:00 app[web.1]: [79382bce-34fd-4faa-958c-15b6ce8adf1f]   
2016-11-14T20:51:59.511536+00:00 app[web.1]: [79382bce-34fd-4faa-958c-15b6ce8adf1f] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:17:in `new'
```

As you can see I get the home page but when I try to get signup form I got error. Everything is working ok locally, REST actions on users resource are working fine locally. 
This output is interesting for me:

```
"PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist"
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This Issue was appeared because of some migration issue.To up migrations in heroku enter below command **

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

After this,check whether all migrations are up or not.If you get any issue check with that migration.

Comment: I checked individual migrations and saw that some migrations for tagging funcionality where making problems, so I destroyed them with 'rails destroy migration CreateTaggins' and now everything is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to run migrations on Heroku, just run in the shell inside your project:

`heroku run rails db:migrate`